# Any alternatives to SHGetKnownFolderPath with user token for Windows XP?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-xp, known-folders

My software is still required to support Windows XP. In it I am calling [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API from the Windows service to obtain user-specific paths (such as `FOLDERID_Desktop`) by `hToken`. Since that API is not supported on XP, I'm curious if there are any alternative ways to do this on that OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper function to use would be [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing either  `NULL` or `-1` as the access token:

> hToken [in]
>
> Type: HANDLE
>
> An access token that can be used to represent a particular user. It is usually set to NULL, but it may be needed when there are
>   multiple users for those folders that are treated as belonging to a
>   single user. The most commonly used folder of this type is My
>   Documents. The calling application is responsible for correct
>   impersonation when hToken is non-NULL. It must have appropriate
>   security privileges for the particular user, and the user's registry
>   hive must be currently mounted. See Access Control for further
>   discussion of access control issues.
>
> Assigning the hToken parameter a value of -1 indicates the Default User. This allows clients of SHGetFolderLocation to find folder
>   locations (such as the Desktop folder) for the Default User. The
>   Default User user profile is duplicated when any new user account is
>   created, and includes special folders such as My Documents and
>   Desktop. Any items added to the Default User folder also appear in any
>   new user account.

Comment: Very nice find. Appreciate it! In my case though, `SHGetFolderPath` its twin API, would work better as the one returning an actual folder path. Thanks again!

Comment: `SHGetFolderLocation()` returns a `PIDL` that you can convert to a path using `SHGetPathFromIDList()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, I know. But why use two APIs when I can do it with one. (In my case I need it for a desktop path only.)

Comment: @ahmd0: `SHGetFolderPath()` (and `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()`) did not exist when PIDLs were first introduced, they were added later. So it all depends on how far back you need to support older OS versions. If you have to go further back than Win2K, then you can use `GetProcAddress()` to load `SHGetFolderPath()` and if it is nt available then provide your own wrapper that uses `SHGetFolderLocation()` and `SHGetPathFromIDList()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Luckily XP is as far as I need to go. Man, I can't imagine anyone using Win2K these days. We're actually "praying" now for people to stop using XP, which is pretty ancient by today's standards anyway and gives developers a lot of headache (as you probably know.)

Comment: @ahmd0: I still use XP for all of my development VMs :)  Fairly light-weight, no UAC bull**** to deal with, etc.